# Upgrade of SAP B1 from version 9.2 PL 07 to 10.0 PL 02

Tags: sapb1

I'm encountering the following problem. When upgrading SAP B1 database from 9.2 PL 07 version to 10.0 PL 02 version (on MS SQL) i get an error -5002 - internal error, on Dashboard Packages object. Does anyone had a similar case? Maybe someone knows the solution for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please update to 9.3 pl6 min. before upgrade to 10

Comment: Strange, but this helped. Thank you a lot!